# Schmitt trigger output waveform coming as sinewave

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, simulation, proteus, schmitt-trigger

I am new to Proteus. I tried simulating an easy circuit which was a Schmitt trigger using an op-amp.

After simulation, the output waveform was an sinewave instead of rectangular wave.

Any idea where I made a mistake?

Please let me know as I have to simulate further circuits in Proteus.

[image]

Comment: You should [edit] to state your supply voltages and signal frequency. (It's hard to make out on the timebase but it seems to be using a capital 'M' for what is probably milliseconds and should be 'm'. Your feedback resistors are very low values.

Comment: Increase R1 >1k .  Pin numbers are correct yet response appears as inputs are reversed.  Reduce Vin by same ratio 10:1

Comment: The royal society for the prevention of cruelty to op-amps are going to be informed. Hold-on, it's a 741 - forget that threat.

Comment: To explain Andy's comment, Mihir: Are you **Sure** (as in: *really* sure) you want to simulate a 741 in a latching operation? This is not only the worst opamp that money can still buy on this planet, it's especially badly suited for this use case. Maybe start your simulation with an *ideal* opamp first, then use a sensible opamp model instead of the 741.

Comment: Understand that the BW at max gain is limited by GBW

Comment: Your plot shows a clean non-inverting gain of 2. This would be expected... if your opamp inputs were reversed. So I suspect you're not simulating what you think you are.